# ¿Cómo usar tidyr::pivot_longer para pivotar un gran número de variables que pertenecen a grupos conocidos?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

Necesito pivotar una gran cantidad de columnas, cuyo nombre no necesariamente sigue un patrón.

Para ilustrar, cree un dataframe de ejemplo, así como las agrupaciones que necesito y un resultado esperado de ejemplo para un par de combinaciones en las variables de identificación que necesito conservar sin pivotar (ID e ID2)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

# Ejemplo dataframe
df <- data.frame(interview_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                 edad_l_id = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2),                 
                 matrix(rnorm(200), ncol = 20))

# Nombres de variables (que no siguen un patrón)
colnames(df) <- c("ID","ID2","var1","ejem","exam","x1","sit","var2","ehem","pilot","y2","pot","var3","nom","ejec","z3","mar",
                  "var4","lom","yip","u4","tom")

# Agrupación de variables necesitada
namelist <- list(
  group1 = c("var1","ejem","exam","x1","sit"),
  grupo2 = c("var2","ehem","pilot","y2","pot"),
  grupo3 = c("var3","nom","ejec","z3","mar"),
  grupo4 = c("var4","lom","yip","u4","tom"))
```

Ahora, este es el resultado esperado, para las primeras combinaciones de ID e ID2:

```
ID  ID2 group1  group1_val  group2  group2_val  group3  group3_val  group4  group4_val
1   1   var1    -1.37       var2    -0.23       var3     1.49       var4    -1.36
1   1   ejem    -0.72       ehem    0.82        nom      0.37       lom     0.15
1   1   exam    0.49        pilot   0.18        ejec     0.69       yip     -1.01
1   1   x1      -0.90       y2      -0.62       z3       0.48       u4      -0.93
1   1   sit     2.26        pot     -1.10       mar      0.11       tom     0.77
1   2   var1    0.78        var2    -0.20       var3     0.36       var4    -0.59
1   2   ejem    -0.76       ehem    -1.29       nom      0.94       lom     -0.59
1   2   exam    -1.82       pilot   -1.62       ejec     0.44       yip     -0.04
1   2   x1      0.92        y2      0.39        z3      -0.69       u4      0.65
1   2   sit     -1.05       pot     0.79        mar      1.01       tom    -0.48
1   3   etc.........
```

etc
etc

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
namelist %>% 
  map2_dfr(names(namelist),
           ~ df %>% 
                select(ID, ID2, any_of(.x)) %>% 
                mutate(group = .y) %>% 
                pivot_longer(-c(ID, ID2, group))
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(group, name),
              names_glue = "{group}_{name}")
```

Comentarios:

- `map2_dfr` nos permite iterar sobre dos listas, la primera la de los datos (`.x`) y la segunda, la de los nombres de cada elemento (`.y`)
- Primero pivoteamos el `data.frame` a lo largo para generar cada grupo, seleccionando las columnas definidas en cada elemento de la lista
- Luego simplemente pivoteamos a lo ancho.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Intenté correr este código y me arroja como error:
Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! `cols` must select at least one column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Al menos en mi entorno y con los datos que has dado de ejemplo, el código que te pasé funciona bien. ¿Has hecho algún cambio? ¿son otros los datos?